# Шифрование ячеек БД с помощью SQL команд и c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, шифрование, база-данных

Есть простейшее приложение-клиент для БД созданной в SQL Server 2014 EXPRESS, требуется шифровать данные в ячейках. Нашел алгоритм и команды шифрования, но средствами SQL Server. Подскажите как реализовать шифрование и дешифрование данных в клиенте. Данные выводятся с помощью DataGredView, редактирование с помощью TextBox.

Команды вставки:

```
cvetTableAdapter.Insert(textBox2.Text);
cvetTableAdapter.Fill(gIBDDDataSet.Cvet);
```

Команды обновления:

```
cvetBindingSource.EndEdit();
cvetTableAdapter.Update(gIBDDDataSet.Cvet);
cvetTableAdapter.Fill(gIBDDDataSet.Cvet);
```

Команды удаления:

```
cvetTableAdapter.Delete(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), textBox3.Text);
cvetTableAdapter.Fill(gIBDDDataSet.Cvet);
```

Программный код для создания ключей для демонстрации. Ключи создаются в самой БД. С этим проблем нет.

```
USE [EncryptedDB]
GO
— Создание асимметричного ключа, зашифрованного
— парольной фразой StrongPa$$w0rd!
CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY MyAsymmetricKey
WITH ALGORITHM = RSA_2048
ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'StrongPa$$w0rd!'
GO
— Создание симметричного ключа, зашифрованного
— асимметричным ключом.
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY MySymmetricKey
WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
ENCRYPTION BY ASYMMETRIC KEY MyAsymmetricKey
GO
```

Вот сама вставка  с шифрованием. От сюда начинаются проблемы, т.к. не понимаю как на c# все это реализовать.

```
USE [EncryptedDB]
GO
DECLARE @SymmetricKeyGUID AS [uniqueidentifier]
SET @SymmetricKeyGUID = KEY_GUID('MySymmetricKey')
IF (@SymmetricKeyGUID IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO [dbo].[CreditCardInformation]
VALUES (01, ENCRYPTBYKEY(@SymmetricKeyGUID,
N'9876-1234-8765-4321'))
```

Вывод данных с дешифрованием. Опять же как внедрить это в функционал приложения.

```
USE [EncryptedDB]
GO
SELECT [PersonID]
CONVERT([nvarchar](32), DECRYPTBYKEY(CreditCardNumber))
AS [CreditCardNumber]
FROM [dbo].[CreditCardInformation]
GO
```

Помогите, уже все облазил нигде толкового ничего нет.

Comment: В дотнете [встроено](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0ss79b2x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) немало способов шифрования. Выбирайте подходящий. А как именно его применить, зависит от способа доступа к БД.

Comment: Т.е. нет смысла использовать возможности SQL Servers?

Comment: Ну почему же нет? Можно использовать. Только если данные шифруются в приложении, то по сети они идут уже зашифрованные. А если на сервере, - то в открытом виде.

Comment: Принял, спасибо!

Comment: Я был неправ. Можно шифровать данные на клиенте (C#), а расшифровывать на сервере (TSQL), и наоборот. Все зависит от того, что нужно обезапасить: **хранение** данных или **пересылку** данных.

Comment: Нужно хранение, так как это реализовывается?